# Sphinx 'latin-1' codec can't encode character' - want to use utf-8

Tags: python, sphinx

I get the following error trying to insert into my rt index:

```
'latin-1' codec can't encode character u'\u2019' in position 126: ordinal not in range(256)
```

It should be using utf-8, not latin-1. In my conf file I have specified:

```
index my_index
{
        type = rt
        path = /path/my_index
        rt_field = content

        charset_type = utf-8
}
```

I am selecting the values for insertion from a database that is utf-8. I am inserting it from Python, using raw sql (no api):

```
cursor_sphinx.execute("replace into my_index (id, content ) values (%s,%s)", (id, content))
```

How can I avoid this?

Comment: As noted on sphinx forum, dont think this is from sphinx. https://www.google.com/search?q=codec+can't+encode+character++in+position suggests that this is a python issue. AFAIK python has a specific unicode string type u"..." you should use.

Comment: Added the python tag.

Comment: How did you create the `cursor_sphinx` object? Did you specify the database encoding when connecting? (Just having the correct encoding set in the database itself might not matter at all...)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, inserting as content.encode("utf-8") did the trick, although I don't see why this is necessary when the first database is utf-8 and my .py file specifies # coding=UTF-8

Comment: The encoding comment in the .py only defines what encoding you wrote the code in, it has no effect on the end result. Your first database connector is supplying the 'content' data in Python's Unicode string type which, for clarity, is not UTF-8. This would be normal.

Comment: The latin-1 could refer to anything. Maybe you are printing to the terminal and the default encoding for the terminal is latin-1. Without more context is hard to tell where's the problem.